# Wake Kindle Fire from sleep and bypass lock screen

Tags: android, kindle-fire

This could possibly be related to it being a Kindle Fire with Advertisements but I have an alarm manager that launches an activity and wakes up the device and bypasses the lock screen using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

But this doesn't seem to work on the Kindle Fire, the activity is launched in the background and is waiting when I unlock the device but the device never actually wakes up or bypasses the lock screen.

There's no security on the lock screen but it is the Kindle Fire with advertisements.

Comment: I have the same problem with a kindle fire HD 10 (7th gen) without ads. Did you manage to solve that issue somehow?

Comment: No sorry, we ended up flashing cyanogen for our purposes as it was an internal project

Comment: To bad there is no mod for the 7th gen so far =/ Thanks for replying!